# Python scraping tables

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I started practicing in web-scraping few days ago. I made this code to extract data from a wikipedia page. There are several tables that classify mountains based on their height. However there is a problem with the size of the matrices. Some of them contain 5 columns while others 4. So I made this algorithm to extract all the names and the attributes of the mountains into separate lists. My approach was to create a length list that contains the number of
`<td>` within the `<tr>` tags. The algorithm finds which table contains four columns and fills the column in excess (in the case of 5 columns) with NONE. However, I believe that there is a more efficient and more pythonic way to do it especially in the part where I use the `find.next()` function repedetly.  Any suggestions are welcomed.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

URL="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mountains_by_elevation"
content=requests.get(URL).content

soup=BeautifulSoup(content,'html.parser')

all_tables=soup.find_all("table",{"class":["sortable", "plainrowheaders"]})

mountain_names=[]
metres_KM=[]
metres_FT=[]
range_Mnt=[]
location=[]

lengths=[]


for table in range(len(all_tables)):

  x=all_tables[table].find("tr").find_next("tr")
  y=x.find_all("td")
  lengths.append(len(y))  

  for row in all_tables[table].find_all("tr"):

        try:
            mountain_names.append(row.find("td").text)
            metres_KM.append(row.find("td").find_next("td").text)
            metres_FT.append(row.find("td").find_next("td").find_next("td").text)
            if lengths[table]==5:
                range_Mnt.append(row.find("td").find_next("td").find_next("td").find_next("td").text)
            else:
                range_Mnt.append(None)
            location.append(row.find("td").find_next("td").find_next("td").find_next("td").find_next("td").text)
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Is the code working as expected?

Comment: Yes, totally. However i want to find -out a better way to scrape tables rather than using find_next() all the time.

Comment: Alright; By the way Welcome to Code Review. Hopefully you receive good answers!

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Answer (score 2):

You're just looping on the rows, but not on the cells:

```
 for row in all_tables[table].find_all("tr"):
```

Rather than using multiple `find_next("td")` one after the other, add another loop using `row.find_all('td')` and append each row and cell to a 2D array.

Manipulating a 2D array is much easier and will make your code look much cleaner than `row.find("td").find_next("td").find_next("td")`.

Good luck!

---

Those questions contain some answers that might interest you:

- [How to convert an HTML table to an array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870667/how-to-convert-an-html-table-to-an-array-in-python)
- [python BeautifulSoup parsing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377533/python-beautifulsoup-parsing-table)

To be more specific, this code snippet from [@shaktimaan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/531036/shaktimaan):

```
data = []
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'lineItemsTable'})
table_body = table.find('tbody')

rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Because I am new in scraping  and in python generally what I understand is that you mean to replace the (try) part of my code with this loop? I did it by the way but data list is empty.